# Using regular expressions for filter-mapping

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, url-pattern

I know I cannot use regular expressions for the url-pattern of a filter-mapping, but I wanted to know if it is possible somehow to map the filter using something like `/foo/.+/*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As to wildcard matching, the `<url-pattern>` only supports prefix (`/folder/*`) or suffix (`*.extension`) matching.

If you want more finer grained matching like as possible with Apache HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`, then use [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) or [OCPSoft Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) instead. They support `mod_rewrite`-like expressions by XML configuration.

Answer (score 2):

No. URL Patterns in Servlet does not support regular expressions. They can be only of these below three types:

- `Exact Pattern` For Ex, `/folder/abc.html`, `/folder/abc`
- `Directory Pattern` For Ex, `/folder/abc/*`
- `Extension Pattern` For Ex, `*.js`, `*.reports` etc