# What is the meaning of the leading slash / in Tomcat's <url-pattern>?

Tags: regex, tomcat, url-pattern

I know I cannot use regular expressions for the `<url-pattern>` of a filter-mapping, but is it possible to use a [directory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10891717/1864054) to specify any url containing the word `myuniqws` as in:

```
https://my.hostname.org/myuniqws/myport/soap?wsdl
```

I am thinking of perhaps this would be the correct syntax:

```
<url-pattern>/*myuniqws*</url-pattern>
```

but I have not been able to find documentation for the exact rule of Tomcat's  `<url-pattern>` syntax.

Will the above regex work as I desire?

---

**Update:**

Thanks to the answer below, I discovered the following section in the Java Servlet Specification, which basically answers my questions.

**12.2 Specification of Mappings**

In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define
mappings:

- A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for
  path mapping.
- A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
- The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
- A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
- All other strings are used for exact matches only.

If the effective `web.xml` (after merging information from fragments and annotations) contains any url-patterns that are mapped to multiple servlets then the deployment must fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you mean the `<url-pattern>` for filter mappings in `web.xml`. You might not know this, but `web.xml` is defined as part of the Java Servlet Specification. You can find full documentation for the 3.1 version (currently, the latest and greatest) here:

https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/index.html

If you read section 12.2 ("Specification of Mappings") you can see exactly what kinds of patterns are recognized, including the prefix-mapping you are requesting above.

**EDIT 2014-11-04**:
You should know that `CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml` (or `CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` if you have one) is the default configuration for all web applications deployed on Tomcat and that your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml` is the configuration specific for your own web application. Both of these files should have the following `xmlns` statements and therefore indicate to you (by their URIs) that they are covered by the Java Servlet Specification (or at least Java EE, which includes the servlet spec):

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know that Tomcat's `web.xml` is actually the same as `web.xml` in the Java Servlet Specification. +1 and accepting.